# C: Using 3D array in struct?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm using a struct with a 3D array. The array is defined like this

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned int s;
    unsigned int E;
    unsigned int b;
    unsigned int* data;
} cache;
```

In a function where I try to make an instance of this struct, I'm trying to define the data component but I keep getting the compiler error

error: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Werror]

The function's arguments are this;

```
cache* make_cache(unsigned int s, unsigned int E, unsigned int b)
```

And I try to make the data part using the code

```
unsigned int data[S][E][2];
c->data = data;
```

Anyone have an ideas as to why this is?

Comment: `unsigned int *` and `unsigned int (*)[E][2]` are different types, thus a sad-face compiler.

Answer (score 0):

It's because unsigned int* is different from a unsigned int[S][E][2] pointer. One is a pointer to an array of specific size.

Instead you can assign the pointer to the first element of the array or cast.

For instance the following works because this is a pointer to an int (specifically the 0th element of your array)

```
c->data = &data[0][0][0]
```